# How to target a hyperlink JQuery

Tags: jquery

Please assist. I am trying to show an initially hidden div (con) upon the clicking of a link. Please see my code below - I used an alert to indicate that something is happening however no pop up appeared. Any assistance is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="status.css">
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".con").hide();
});


$("a[href$='.php']").click(function(){
alert("Hi");
$(".con").show();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#.php">Test</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is fine what is the problem?

Comment: Not sure if it's just an error from posting the code, but you don't actually have a `div.con` element in your markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click handler code is outside of your `document.ready` so the code will run before the elements exist and therefore will do nothing.

Put it inside the `ready` handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".con").hide();

    $("a[href$='.php']").click(function () {
        alert("Hi");
        $(".con").show();
    });
});
```